# SSH - Grep with special chars and *

Tags: ssh, grep

I'm looking to search some files via SSH with the grep command but I have some special chars.
The string I'm looking for is:
`"$GLOBALS['....'];"`

I tried this one

```
grep -r -H "\$GLOBALS\\['*'\\]\;" /var/www/
```

but nothing happens. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RE actually matches `"$GLOBALS['''''''];"` with one or more `'` there.
try this one:

```
grep -rHP "[$]GLOBALS\['.*?']\;" file
```

I use [$] instead of \$, is because ESCAPE IS SOMEHOW TRICKY, some environment you need use `\\\$`.

Update, less than 10 chars inside the []:

```
grep -rHP "[$]GLOBALS\['.{0,10}']\;" file
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to search for a string that contains less than 10 chars between the [ ], is there any way to do that ?
PS: I'm trying to create a script to check infected files and clean them.